# Angular Child Component Not Detecting Changes

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

I have a simple Angular component which includes an Angular Material ProgressBar, this component is a child of a 'Container' component. An Observable stream of data from the NgRx Store into the container component is updating, but the child component which is passed the data does not detect the changes. A new object is being created every time the data changes and I enforce immutability in my Store. I am implementing `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` (though when removed makes no difference to this problem).

The container's only responsibility is to subscribe to an Observable stream of data from the NgRx Store and pass it to the child component as follows:

```
  public progressBarData$: Observable<ProgressBarData | null>;

  constructor(
    private store: Store<AppState>
  ) {

    this.progressBarData$ = this.store.pipe(
      select(fromCoreSelectors.programSelectors.selectProgressBarDeterminateData),
      tap(data => {
        console.log(`selectProgressBarDeterminateData: `, data);
      })
    );

  }
```

An `async` pipe manages the subscription for me as the data is passed into the child as follows:

```
<app-progress-bar-determinate [progressBarData]="progressBarData$ | async"></app-progress-bar-determinate>
```

The child component is nice and simple as follows:

```
export class ProgressBarDeterminateComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() progressBarData: ProgressBarData | null = null;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  };

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log(`ngOnChanges`, changes);
  };

}
```

I included `ngOnChanges` so I could see what changes the child detects.

The child component's template is as follows:

```
<div *ngIf="progressBarData?.show === true" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0;">
  <div fxFlex="nogrow" class="mat-elevation-z4" style="width: 320px; height: 64px; background-color: white; z-index: 4;">

    <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="center center" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">

      <div fxFlex="nogrow" *ngIf="progressBarData?.message">
        <p>{{progressBarData?.message}}</p>
      </div>

      <mat-progress-bar mode="determinate" [value]="progressBarData?.value" color="accent" style="width: 240px;"></mat-progress-bar>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

To display the ProgressBar I dispatch an Action which creates a new object in the Reducer which causes the Selector to emit a new object. A different Action hides the ProgressBar. All fine.

In my application I have a very processor intensive routine (which lasts approximately 10 seconds) which I want to display the ProgressBar throughout and then hide it when everything is complete. This intensive routine starts when a button is clicked and the button function dispatches two Actions; Display the ProgressBar and start the routine. When the application is launched I can see the initial values from the Store being passed into the ProgressBar child component as the `ngOnChanges` console logs out the default `ProgressBarData` values.

When the Start button is clicked I know both Actions are being dispatched. I can see the Reducer updating the Store with a new `ProgressBarData` object and the container component console logs out that it received the new object and that the `show` property is `true` along with the correct `message` string. However, the child component doesn't appear to receive the new object at its `@Input()`. `ngOnChanges` does not detect anything, the ProgressBar remains resolutely hidden. I also created a `setter` on the `@Input()` to log out if a new value was received, but nothing was received even though I could see the parent container had received a new object in it's subscription.

As a sanity check I temporarily placed a second button on the screen but this button only dispatches the Action to display the ProgressBar. When clicked the ProgressBar displays instantly and if I then click the original button the routine runs and after the routine the Action is dispatched to hide the ProgressBar and it hides, as expected.

After nearly two days on this I am starting to go around in circles so I thought I would ask for a fresh pair of eyes, as it were. It is as if change detection pauses while the routine is running and then when complete resumes again.

Any thoughts, suggestions or questions are very welcome.

**Update 01**

The intensive routine is trigerred by dispatching an NgRx Action and immediately before this I dispatch another Action to display the ProgressBar as follows:

```
        // Dispatch an Action to show the Progress Bar.
        this.store.dispatch(fromCoreActions.ProgramActions.showProgressBarDeterminateFromTaskGeneratorEffects(
          { message: "Calculating Tasks, please wait..." }
        ));

        // Dispatch an Action to generate the Tasks.
        this.store.dispatch(fromAppPlanActions.TasksGeneratorActions.generateTasks());
```

I have found, almost by accident, that if I wrap the second Action within a `setTimeout()` function everything works! as follows:

```
// Dispatch an Action to show the Progress Bar.
this.store.dispatch(fromCoreActions.ProgramActions.showProgressBarDeterminateFromTaskGeneratorEffects(
  { message: "Calculating Tasks, please wait..." }
));

// Use setTimeout to force the ProgressBar to display before the Action is dispatched to generate Tasks.
setTimeout(() => {

  // Dispatch an Action to generate the Tasks.
  this.store.dispatch(fromAppPlanActions.TasksGeneratorActions.generateTasks());

}, 0);
```

That wasn't the end of it. I then faced the same problem when trying to update the ProgressBar's `value` property by dispatching Actions incrementally through the intensive process. Again the child component initially just ignored the changing data being passed to it from its parent container using an async pipe. Wrapping the dispatch of the Action to update the NgRx Store within a `setTimeout()` again forced the issue (somehow).

Many thanks for those who suggested ideas and to Chris for setting up the StackBlitz. Please share any thoughts as it's an opportunity to learn and improve.

Comment: Any chance your progress bar is being hidden by a parent *ngIf ?

Comment: Interesting suggestion thanks. There is an `*ngIf` in the child component (I updated the question to include the code) but it all works fine when clicking the test button to only display the ProgressBar component and not trigger the routine, so I feel this is fine. But welcome a challenge on that.

Comment: Well, if ngOnChanges isn’t firing at all, then your component probably isn’t being instantiated, so something is preventing it.  Double check and see if ngOnInit fires.

Comment: I did think that originally so I set the outer div to display a pink border and moved the `*ngIf` back a level so the component was always displayed, just not the body of it. Sure enough the pink border displayed fine throughout. I will try it again now though to be sure.

Comment: Is this "processor intensive routine" running on the main thread or are you using a web worker? From what you've described, it almost sounds like the UI is hanging due to the main thread being block from the processing that is going on. Minko Gechev demos something similar in [this video](https://youtu.be/ybNj-id0kjY?t=394). You'll see he's calculating the fibonocci sequence hundreds of times which is very processor intensive and blocks the UI from rendering.

Comment: If you replace this processor intensive routine with something trivial, does the component still not update correctly?

Comment: Good question Paul. It is on the main thread and does appear as if the UI is hanging. Curiously though when the routine if finished it doesn't hurridly catch back up again, possibly causing a flash of the ProgressBar, it appears to just ignore any changes.

Comment: My sanity check button doesn't perform anything but simply dispatches the Action to update the Store which in turn displays the ProgressBar. Works fine. The two buttons are side-by-side.

Comment: @BizzyBob. Just tried again setting the ProgressBar border to pink and moving the `ngIf` back a level and it is instantiated and permanently displays. Good check though.

Comment: I suggest attempting to create a Minimal Reproducible Example, preferably on something like StackBlitz.

Comment: @TDC I'm not able to reproduce, see if you can add to this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vflbze?file=src/app/progress-bar-determinate/progress-bar-determinate.component.html

Comment: I have a solution, though I'm not entirely settled on why it works! My intensive routine is triggered by an NgRx Action being dispatched. Immediately preceding this I also dispatch an Action to display the ProgressBar with a 'Please wait...' message payload. If I wrap the second Action to stat the routine within a `setTimeout` the first Action to show the ProgressBar completely resolves; the Reducer updates, the container component receives the new value in the Observable stream and importantly the child component detects the changing `@Input()` and the ProgressBar is displayed.

Comment: Added an update in my original post to help explain my solution.